# Measure of infinite independent sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ be a countable set, $P_1,P_2,...$ a sequence of non-negative numbers such that $\sum P_i=1$, and $\mu$ the measure $\mu(A)=\sum\limits_{x_i\in A}P_i$. Show that $X$ cannot contain an infinite sequence of independent sets $A_1,A_2,...$ such that, for all $i$, $\mu(A_i)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hint: Start by observing that every point $x\in X$ must lie in one of the four sets $A_1\cap A_2$, $A_1^C\cap A_2$, $A_1\cap A_2^C$, or $A_1^C\cap A_2^C$. Thus the measure of the one-point set $\{x\}$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{4}$.

I'm stuck with the hint. Obviously $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't have to be independent since they could both contain $x$, so we're not assuming their measure is $\frac{1}{2}$. So how can we say what the measure of $\{x\}$ is? Even given this, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Independent is not the same thing as disjoint. Actually, if you have events $A,B$ such that $P(A),P(B) > 0$ that are disjoint, they cant be independent.

Comment: By independence we have $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2)=\frac14$. It does not prevent the sets $A_i$ from both containing $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that such an infinite sequence of $A_i$ would exist.

For any such $A_i$, because $\mu(A_i) = \frac{1}{2}$, we also have $\mu(A_i^{c}) = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, due to the independence, we conclude that $\mu(A_1 \cap A_2^{c}) = \mu(A_1) \cdot \mu(A_2^c) = \frac{1}{4}$, and the same holds for the other three sets in the hint. Because these sets are a partition of $X$, we must have that $\{x\}$ is a subset of one of them, resulting in $\mu(\{x\}) \leq \frac{1}{4}.$

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider
$$\mathfrak{P}_{n} := \{B_1\cap\dots\cap B_n ~|~ B_i = A_i \text{ or } B_{i} = A_{i}^c,~ i\in \{1,\dots,n\}\} $$
This is again a partition of $X$, where each set has measure equal to $2^{-n}$. Conclude that we have $\mu(\{x\}) \leq 2^{-n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why it's a contradiction?

Comment: Taking the limit $n \to \infty$ you get $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, which implies $\mu(X) = 0$ as $X$ is countable.